# Не могу понять , почему не работает обработчик кликов(последние 2 строки скрипта). Нужно , чтобы анимация останавливалась по клику на объект h1(

Tags: javascript, click, clearinterval

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Изучаем DOM</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1 id="heading">Привет, мир!</h1>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
 <script>
 var move="right";
 var offset=0;
 $("#heading").offset({left: offset, top: offset});
 var moveHead = function() {
       if (move==="right"){
         $("#heading").offset({left:offset});
        offset++;
        if(offset>200){
          offset=0;
          move="down";
          }

      }
       else if (move==="down"){
         $("#heading").offset({top:offset});
          offset++;
        if(offset>200){
          offset=200;
          move="left";
        }
      } else if (move==="left"){
      $("#heading").offset({left:offset});
        offset--;
        if(offset<0){
          offset=200;
          move ="up";
        }
      }
      else if (move==="up") {
        $("#heading").offset({top:offset});
        offset--;
        if (offset<0){
          offset=0;
          move="right"
        }
      }
    };
var interval = setInterval(moveHead,20);
 $("h1").click(clearInterval(interval));

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: читайте чаще доки, почему Вы в clearInterval передали функцию?

Comment: обновил ответ, добавил скрипт, можете пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `var interval = setInterval(moveHead,20); $("h1").click(clearInterval(interval));`
в функцию clearInterval передается идентификатор setInterval, который необходимо остановить.

```js
 var move="right";
 var offset=0;
 $("#heading").offset({left: offset, top: offset});
 function moveHead() {
       if (move==="right"){
         $("#heading").offset({left:offset});
        offset++;
        if(offset>200){
          offset=0;
          move="down";
          }

      }
       else if (move==="down"){
         $("#heading").offset({top:offset});
          offset++;
        if(offset>200){
          offset=200;
          move="left";
        }
      } else if (move==="left"){
      $("#heading").offset({left:offset});
        offset--;
        if(offset<0){
          offset=200;
          move ="up";
        }
      }
      else if (move==="up") {
        $("#heading").offset({top:offset});
        offset--;
        if (offset<0){
          offset=0;
          move="right"
        }
      }
    };
var interval = setInterval(moveHead,30);
$("#heading").on('click', function(){
  clearInterval(interval)
});
```

Comment: в этом случае анимация вообще не происходит

Comment: возможно, у меня получилось бы помочь, если бы была ссылка на песочницу или кусок html кода. Давать советы только по чтению кода без его пробы получается наощупь

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Paprika добавил весь код , помогите пожалуйста)